# Java synchronized() keyword -- protection against changes of the object referenced in the field?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I know that

```
synchronized(objA) {
    objA.readSomething();
}
```

protect object from being modified by another thread. But what if objA is declared as

```
class A {
    public B objB; 
    public void readSoemthing() {
       objB.readSomething();
    }
}
```

and during the following block, another thead calls `objB.modifySomething()`? Suppose that thread somehow has its own reference to `objB`.

Will that be safe? if not, what's the proper way of handling it (i.e. I don't want any thread to modify anything inside A, even if it's a field that points to a different object, I don't want that object being modified).

```
synchronized(objA) {
    objA.readSomething();  // at this point antoher thread calls objB.modifySomething()
}
```

Comment: `synchronized` does not protect the object from being modified. Correct use of `synchronize` does so, but that's much harder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of your question is incorrect. The synchronized block only makes sure that no other thread can enter a block of code that is also synchronized on the object referenced by objA while the synchronized block is executing.

So any other thread might modify `objA` concurrently, unless all the methods that modify `objA` are synchronized.

Now that you know that, you also know that any other thread can get objB from objA and do whatever it wants with objB, unless all the methods of `objB` are also synchronized on `objA`.

This is why encapsulation is critical in thread-safe classes. All the methods accessing (read or write) shared state of an object should go through a synchronized method of that object. And the shared state should never be exposed to the outside.

Comment: A source of confusion may also be that you are using `objA` as the locking object. In the above answer this is stated, but let me stress it again: In the `synchronized` statement you can use any object you want. Any other code trying to `synchronize` the _same_ object will have to wait. I don't know how it is in Java, but in C# it is actually common to create a separate `object lockObject = new object();` specifically for locking, rather than using an instance variable or `this`. So then the code would be `synchronized(lockObject) { // do something with a, or any other variable; }`.

Answer (score 2):

That would not be thread safe.  That's why you should "encapsulate" objB inside of objA by disallowing direct access to it (i.e. make it private).

Answer (score 1):

> I know that
>
> ```
> synchronized(objA) {
>     objA.readSomething();
> }
> ```
>
> protect object from being modified by another thread. But what if objA
>   is declared as

This doesn't prevent `objA` from being modified by another thread, it ensures that another thread cannot obtain the monitor of `objA` while calling `objA.readSomething()` from the piece of code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really protecting against modification with `synchronized`. All you are doing is preventing two threads from accessing that same method concurrently (or any other method or code block that uses the same object instance for synchronization). Synchronization is about concurrency (i.e. multi-threading) not write protection.

If you absolutely don't want modifications you should use the modifiers `private` or `protected` so that the respective `write` method is only accessed from the class(es) you want.

If on the other hand you want to avoid concurrent modifications, or avoid reading while writing (and vice-versa) you need to synchronize the `read` and `write` methods with the same object (in your case ObjA). It might also make sense to use the right modifiers to protect the methods from being accessed from classes you don't want.

Also remember that if a `Thread` has gained access to the synchronisation monitor of an object it can call all the methods that are synchronising on the same object.